# modal does not hide and data does not show after "POST"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

[modal not hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxgwz.png)

[new post not appearing at last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ay4T.png)

[modal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFz6K.png)

[ajax get/post code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vDmT.png)

[ajax get/post code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlJlE.png)

Comment: Could you give us more details about the setup and can give you some code? Don't use images for code.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557